# How to load js file and javascript before all other javascripts and js files?

Tags: javascript, load

I have an colorbox.js file and javascript code like this:

```
echo '<script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width: "830", height: "620"});
      });

    </script>';
echo '<a href="prices.php" id="iframe">see the pricelist</a>';
```

When I click to a link, its opening as an iframe popup through colorbox. But if I click it before page is loaded completely, it's opening as a normal link on a new page (doesn't pop up as an iframe). So how can I make the colorbox script load first, before all other javascripts and files. So maybe I can prevent it opening as a normal page.
Thank you.

Comment: There has to be another error. Script tags that exist in the page initially run synchronously. Since the script tag is in the HTML before the `a` tag - it will run before it. Consider posting the HTML result and not the PHP echo.

Comment: No matter where you put it, `$(document).ready()` will not fire until the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have placed the colorbox's  tag before your custom  tag. Colorbox ideally should have been loaded, before your script is executed. Also, document.ready() will ensure all DOM elements are available before your code gets triggered.

Can you please post a JS Fiddle that replicates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function in the head tag it will execute immedialely, before the DOM is fully parsed. And that is solved using `document.ready`

if you want to execute a block of code that you want to be able to run both in `$(document).ready()` function and earlier as well, then define a function and call it early and put it in `$(document).ready()` as well.

```
// define this in the global scope or some other publicly available scope (not inside a document.ready() call).
function yourFunc() {
   // put your code here
}

$(document.ready(function() {
    yourFunc();
});
```

you can put this function up in the head, after calling the jquery library, as you'll need jQuery lib to execute your `iframe` code